# OR in where clause when working with nested includes or joins with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have to use OR in where clause when working with nested includes with association.
I have an ActiveRecord query as follows:

```
  Inventory.includes(:category,:inventory_tiers,:modifiers=>[:modifier_measures,:modifier_tiers])
  .where(
    :categories => { category_tag: 'Dry'},
    :location_id =>12,
    :inventory_tiers => {:tier => 1}),
    modifiers: {category_tag:"Wet"},
    modifier_tiers: {tier:1}
)
```

in which where clause uses AND for all conditions.
but I want to use OR for last two conditions, something like:

```
Inventory.includes(:category,:inventory_tiers,:modifiers=>[:modifier_measures,:modifier_tiers]).where("categories.category_tag=? AND location_id=? AND inventory_tiers.tier = ? OR modifiers.category_tag=? OR modifier_tiers.tier=?", "Wet",12,1,"Wet",1).select("inventories.id,inventories.name,inventories.photo,inventory_tiers.sell_price, modifiers.id,modifiers.name,modifiers.price,modifier_measures.id as measure_id,modifier_measures.name as measure,modifier_measures.price as measure_price,modifier_measures.measure_value")
```

but its not working.
How i can rewrite the syntax?

Comment: first of all that's alot of rails tags for different versions what version are you actually running. that being said you would have to use a string where for the or portion. what is not working about this other than you are probably missing some parens

Comment: What Rails version are you actually using? Please clean up the tags.

Comment: What is "not working"? Error messages? Expected behavior? Actual Behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, without knowing the actual version of Rails you're using, I'll presume it's Rails 3... In which case, I'd suggest using Arel. Something like:

```
Inventory.includes(:category, :inventory_tiers, modifiers: [:modifier_measures, :modifier_tiers])
  .where(categories: { category_tag: 'Dry' }, location_id: 12, inventory_tiers: { tier: 1 })
  .where(Modifier.arel_table[:category_tag].eq("Wet").or(ModifierTier.arel_table[:tier].eq(1)))
```

I haven't tested this, but the above should get you on the right path.